# Snake Scan Ordering

Tags: matlab

I have wrote the snake scan ordering but I don't know whether it is right or wrong!
I firstly coverted the 256*256 matrix to 8*8 matrixs and did snake scan ordering in these small matrixs.
Might you please tell me how to display the consequence vectors?

```
pic=rgb2gray(pic1);
pic=uint8(pic);
C = mat2cell(pic,[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ],[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8]);
celldisp(C);
 % % % % % Converting the cell arrays to vectors in snake scan ordering form % % % % 
X=[];
n=0;
for i=1:32; 
for j=1:32;

    n=n+1;
   C{i,j}=C{i,j}';
    Vn= reshape(C{i,j},1,[]);
    Vn(5:8)=fliplr (Vn(5:8));
    Vn(13:16)=fliplr (Vn(13:16));
    X=[X  Vn];
end 
end
```

Comment: Snake scan is very simple to implement - you just alternate the direction of each row - try it yourself first and then come back for help if you get stuck.

Comment: okay thanks. Just what do you mean by"you just alternate the direction of each row"?

Comment: You do know how snake scan works, right ? For the first row you iterate from 1 to n, for the second row you iterate from n down to 1, and so on...

Comment: yes i knew, you meant i should change the second for loop:                                                   
for j=32:-1:1;

Comment: Excuse me, but i want this Snake Scan Ordering within each 8×8 matrix and not the 256×256 Matrix.

Comment: please look at [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For snake scan ordering of a matrix `M`:

```
M = M.'; %'// matlab works column major - so we first transform the matrix
M(:, 2:2:end) = M(end:-1:1, 2:2:end); %// filp up-down every second column
snake = M(:).'; %'// convert to a single vector.
```

You can see [here](http://ideone.com/LqkiRY) how it works.